# Heroku SSL with website subdomain causing security warnings in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku, subdomain

I keep getting security certificate errors when I access my Heroku app connected to my site's subdomain. So far, I have successfully connected my website's subdomain (news.mysite.com) to my app using a Heroku domains and my nameserver but my site keeps routing to a https:// version of the herokuapp causing browsers to warn users about the sites certificate.

Can I remove the https routing to my app, or ensure that the browsers ignore the security certificate from Heroku?

**CName:**

```
| Host  | Points to                           |
| www   | sheltered-plains-7225.herokuapp.com |
| news  | news.mysite.com                     | <-- Https Errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need `SSL` and wish to use a custom subdomain then you must purchase a license for the subdomain and [Add Endpoint for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint).

Heroku's SSL license is a wildcard that will cover all of it's own subdomains under `*.herokuapp.com`. So `sheltered-plains-7225.herokuapp.com` is covered but `news.mysite.com` is not.

If you do not need SSL then you should change your environment.

in /config/environments/production.rb change

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

to

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

this will route to `http` instead of `https`

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem, I seem to have put force_ssl on true.

Comment: @user2368130 this is the default option it is nothing you did just something rails does for you.

Answer (score 0):

It would normally be within your app that the redirect to https is done.
Unless you have the Heroku SSL endpoint add-on and an SSL certificate it will always error on https.

Comment: Yes, if you wish to use your own domain for SSL then you will need to use the SSL endpoint addon.